find device control character using sql query
I have data in table with string "BFCTADMG00MB00O7nX5" and I want a find the control or any special character through sql query
Please help ?
I have tried multiple things to get it but no luck. Is there any way to check control characters in database?  can we use hex code to check these characters.
I tried below method-
column_name like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9;,\t[:space:]/.*+_-&() $%]%';

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you need to find special character in particular column, and you want to select record.
Then you can use "regex" in where condition.
for example.
Select *
From table_name
where column_name like '%[$&+,:;=?@#|''<>.^*()%!-]%'

